# Why is there a Library Settings over Page?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

After creating my own personal page in SharePoint 13, I notice the blue ribbon has a Library Settings. If I created a Page and not a Library, then why is the Library settings there?
Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you currently in the All Documents view or are you on your page?

Comment: I am in my page. I select Page and see the Library Settings.
I added the screenshots above.

Comment: Edit your post to include them, there is a button to attack images.

Answer (score 2):

pages are contained in a page library since you can apply to pages all the typical settings that you can apply to documents (versioning, approval etc)

Comment: So do all the pages I create go into one Library in my SharePoint13 account, or do each Page Library only create that one Page I created?
Thanks

Comment: they do not go into 'your account', pages will be visible to Others according to their permissions. They go into the default page library that's always there (SITE PAGES). You cannot have multiple page libraries. The most you can have is by activating the publishing features, at that point you will have also the page library called PAGES that typically will contain article pages, so in total, 2 libraries for pages (but 2 different kind of pages that cannot stay together in one library)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in SharePoint is a very rigid hierarchical structure. Farm > Web Application > Site Collection > Web > List and Library.

In your case a page can't live in SharePoint without belonging to a Pages Library. The library have settings for which Content Types are available for the Pages Library. The Content Types define which Page Layouts a Page can have.

On the Web level you have a setting for which Master Page to use. In essence a Page needs a Page Layout which in term need a Master Page.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand. Is this right?
We have five employers who are using SharePoint13. Each employer creates a page.
Employer Page 1
Employer Page 2
Employer Page 3
Employer Page 4
Employer Page 5. 
All of these five separate pages, are by default saved in ONE LIBRARY that holds all the pages.

[image]